# Binding in my user control isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a User control I've created called TextBoxAndMore that contains a textbox (called textBox1) with a "more" button beside it.  On this user control, I have a property called Text.  I'd like this Text property to mirror the text in the textbox.

I'd like this property to be bindable, so that in my XAML I can bind it to a String property called Description in my ViewModel, like this:

```
<my:TextBoxAndMore Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
```

So I have the following code (generated by the propdb snippet):

```
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(TextBoxAndMore),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

And, on the text box, I have this code attached to the TextChanged event handler, the idea being that when the user types in the textbox, the Text property of this user control changes with it:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

However, the end result is that the binding simply doesn't appear to work.  There's no errors in the output window, and my Description property in my ViewModel just doesn't get set (it remains null).

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'm quite new to WPF and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Instead of a `TextChanged` handler, you want to change the binding to be `TwoWay` so that updates made by the user automatically go back to the property.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the XAML to `<my:TextBoxAndMore Text="{Binding Path=Security, Mode=TwoWay}" />` (is that what you meant?) but I still seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to configure 2-way binding:

```
<my:TextBoxAndMore Text="{Binding Path=Description Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

You could also remove the TextChanged event code in the control and also use TwoWay binding to the control's Text property.

Edit:

<-> == two-way binding...

TextBlockInControlsTemplate <-> TextDepPropInControl <-> DescriptionPropInVM

Comment: Thanks.  I've changed my XAML to this, however the Description property of my ViewModel still remains null, whether I have the TextChanged event code in there or not, is there anything else I could be missing?

Comment: Well, in this type of setup, the VM's description shouldn't ever be null (I think??). You should set it to an empty string or some type of default value. Ultimately this is the only real string, everything else is pointers (at least logically).

Comment: It does seem to work now thanks, but I have to leave the TextChanged line in there (as I'm not entirely sure how to "use TwoWay binding to the control's Text property").

Comment: You should be able to bind textBox1.Text to your UserControl's Text property. I'm not exactly sure how your application is put together and what the DataContexts are at that point.

Comment: You could use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` instead of `UIPropertyMetadata` and set that it binds two-way by default. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault.aspx

Comment: @sixlettervariables Thanks! I was actually going to make that a new question when I got around to it, I knew it must be possible as a simple TextBox does it by default without the user needing to explicitly specify TwoWay!